# Consulta PDO cambiando de tabla

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, webservice, http

Necesito que la siguiente consulta realizada a una base de datos mysql con la función de php "PDO" me permita enviar de parametro URL el nombre de la tabla y que esta a su vez retorne en formato JSON todos los datos de la tabla consultada con el webservice a través de un navegador o sistema que permita transformar esa información para ser consolidada. Este es el código:

```
<?php
require('Toro.php');
class Hello
{ 
    function get() 
    {
        echo 'Hello, worlds';
    }
}


class Consulta 
{
    function get($name=null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $usuario = "bd_user";
            $password = "bd_pass";
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd_name', $usuario, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        try
        {
            if ($name != null)
            {
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM" . " " . $name);
                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            else
            {
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla");
            }
            $stmt->execute();

            $data = Array();
            while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
                $data[] = $result;
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

Toro::serve(array(
    "/country" => "Consulta",
    "/country/:alpha" => "Consulta",
));
?>
```

Como se observa en el código el único parámetro que se envía es el ID de un registro, necesito es que ese name se convierta en el nombre de la tabla de la base de datos y permita hacer el select * from $tabla; 
¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Comment: Para la próxima, debes saber que las consultas preparadas son solo para los valores de columnas, no son ni para nombres de tablas ni para nombres de columnas. O sea, no puedes hacer *binding* de un nombre de tabla/columna, no está permitido. En cuanto a lo que comentas del `if` ... `else` ... no veo ni uno ni otro por ninguna parte. Te dejo otra idea por si puede servir: podrías tener una array de tablas válidas, verificar si el nombre de la tabla que fue pasado existe ahí y lanzar la consulta si existe. Si las tablas están en diferentes BD puedes asociar la BD en el array y así conectar.

Comment: esa puede ser una buena idea, intentaré realizarlo asi. El inconveniente principal es que actualmente enlazo un webservice a excel mediante power query, este lanza el siguiente error: "Se alcanzo el extremo del bufer". Asumo por lo anterior que debe ser un problema del web service al momento de cargar los datos de la tabla.

Comment: Erik, @RubenHernandez recordad ir borrando los mensajes obsoletos para dejar la publicacion ordenada y clara. Un saludo